# Different free space filelight vs df -h

Tags: upgrade, disk-usage

**NOTE:** corrected kubuntu versions.

I was trying to upgrade my kubuntu **18.10** to **19.04** but failed due to a lack of free space on my root partition. I have different partitions for root and home directories. So I tried to free up additional space and according to **filelight** (https://utils.kde.org/projects/filelight/) utility I have already free space of **5.5GB** which would be enough to do the upgrade. However, when I run the command **df -h** it shows only about **3.9GB** of free space.

So, why are the numbers so different? How can I achieve df -h showing the correct size of free space on the root partition?

I think, that the upgrade process internally uses df -h to calculate the amount of free space and that's the reason why cannot upgrade my system.

Any help appreciated. If you have any questions, please ask!

Kind regards, Max.

Comment: We do not support end of life versions of Ubuntu. And `df -h` is always correct :-) Things to consider: if a program has a large file open that you have deleted, the inode won't be deleted until the program quits. Check the files system for errors
Execute `tune2fs` to release the space reserved for root

Comment: Do you really mean "kubuntu 8.10 to 9.04"?

Comment: Ubuntu releases are *year.month* in format, so 8.10 means the 2008.October release, a standard release that at that time had 15 months of supported life. Ubuntu 19.04 (from 2019-April) is soon to reach it's EOL & will be off-topic here (standard releases are now 9 months).  The only questions allowed for EOL or ESM releases need to be specific to moving to a supported release; 9.04 is not such as release.  https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Thanks, you are right, of course I mean Upgrade from Kubuntu 18.10 to 19.04! Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Try `df -hH`  (the -H will force df to use decimal/1000 instead of the unix default of binary/1024).  The first '-h' is just my preference...

Comment: Retracted close vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the comments and hints! I finally fixed the problem using `tune2fs` by resetting all reserved blocks on my root partition and now `df -h` also reports 5.5GB of free space

```
sudo tune2fs -m 0 /dev/sdb1
```

[This source](https://odzangba.wordpress.com/2010/02/20/how-to-free-reserved-space-on-ext4-partitions/) also helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The solutio here is:

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/sda3
```

Dolphin and

```
df -h /home/
```

Showing the same values

Comment: Sorry, the first post post didnt look like being posted...